# Как преобразовать в Map

Tags: java, коллекции, потоки-данных, map

Есть некий класс `User`. Как я могу его преобразовать в справочник, по принципу`[номер телефона -> пользователь]`. Знаю, что надо использовать `Map`, но не понимаю, что именно указывать в `<>`. Думал, может использовать `stream`.
P.S. на вход получаю коллекцию пользователей.

```java
public static class User {

        private String name;
        private int age;
        private String phone;

        public User(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public User(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }

        public void setPhone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }
    }
```

Моя реализация, но она выдает ошибку // `Can not resolve method toMap()`

```java
public static int task2(Collection<User> source) {
        Collection<User> users = new ArrayList<>(source);
        Map<Integer, String> map = users.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap());

       return null;
    }
```

Comment: Тебе нужно получить Map, где ключом будет номер телефона, а значением имя? Или Объект User?

Comment: один номер телефона на одного пользователя, все верно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вот:

```
Map<String, User> map = new HashMap<>();
users.forEach(user -> map.put(user.getPhone(), user));
```

Comment: а можно еще небольшой комментарий получить. Почему именно <String, User>

Comment: Если key - номер телефона и value должен быть User. Либо я не так понял ТЗ)

Comment: Спасибо, отлично!!

Answer (score 1):

`stream` вполне можно использовать, но коллектору нужно указать, что брать в качестве ключа и значения. Сделать это можно передав соответствующие функции в `toMap`, например так:

```
Map<String, User> map = users.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(User::getPhone, user -> user)
);
```

`user -> user` можно заменить на `Function.identity()`

В Вашей реализации `Map` был параметризован целым числом и строкой (`Map<Integer, String>`)...

Если это означает что Вы хотите получить справочник `[номер телефона в числовом формате] -> [имя пользователя]`, то нужно будет поменять аргументы в `toMap`:

1. `user -> user` на `User::getName`
2. `User::getPhone` на функцию, которая будет вытаскивать номер телефона и трансформировать его в число, обрабатывая при этом ошибки конвертации и т.д. Очень желательно будт вынести это в отдельный метод